# Setting a trimpot on a power supply

Tags: voltage, potentiometer

[image]

I'm creating a power supply circuit to regulate the power from a 12 V power source to supply flow sensors that will be installed in a tree.

I have a protocol and circuit diagram I am following, but I am confused about how to set the voltage using the trimpot.

Through the calculations I was given, using the resistances of the sensors attached to the circuit, I know that I need to regulate the voltage to 4.94 V; however I cannot figure out how to do that using the 1 kΩ trimpot. This may be dumb, but do I need to hook up the 12 V power source before I am able to set the voltage with the trimpot?

Also, I believe I set the voltage of the trimpot using a multimeter. Does it matter which terminal end of the trimpot I connect the multimeter lead to? I have both terminal ends hooked up to the circuit (per the diagram I am following), and I'm not sure which end to connect the probe to for the reading or if it matters.

[image: power supply circuit diagram]

Comment: Generally yes, calibration requires the circuit to be live.

Comment: That's a current regulator.  The measured voltage on Vo is a function of the resistance of the load connected to Vo (the resistance of sensor1+sensor2+sensor3).  To setup, you need to have the same load connected to Vo that you wish to use in the field.

Comment: Sorry, I was hasty. What Chris says is correct. That will teach me to pay more attention!

Comment: You will also want a Heat sink for 1W=10V drop * 100mA. If you want CW increasing current centre pin 2 goes to 3 on pots numbered, or towards the 12 Ohms.  A formula to calibrate R's is possible

Comment: **There are a few design flaws with this diagram.** 1) the pot is far too sensitive to get 4.94V accurately and has a range from 4.9 to 6.8V and 2) neither current nor voltage is constant with sensor and changes or pot changes ( nor temperature compensated). and the TO-220 is almost too hot without a heat sink and may shut down with 1W. getting wasted.  4) no filter caps  ...  Who designed this?

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt I am a plant physiologist and am following a protocol designed by another lab (also probably a plant person and not an engineer). The power supply is to regulate power to sensors which will measure sap flux in a tree. I'm using a 12 v car battery as power source to be connected to circuit. I did attach the LM 317 to  heat sink. Do you think that is sufficient? I am not an engineer but have no choice but to figure this out so I am open to any and all suggestions/advice

Comment: Seconding @TonyStewartolderthandirt; this circuit needs some major improvements to work reliably. Are you able to change the circuit at all?

Comment: What are your sensors?

Comment: I can change the circuit as much as I need to. The sensors are probes that I made from hypodermic needles with thermocouples inside. There are two probes per sensor and are inserted into the tree one above the other, 10-15 cm apart. The top one is wrapped in a constantan wire and will be heated by the power source (hence the need for voltage regulation). The bottom is not heated. they are then connected to each other and to a connector cable hooked to the power source/circuit and a data logger. The temp diff between the two probes is calculated into sap flow rate

Comment: The probes are 2cm long and need 0.2 watts of power. The resistances on each probe vary, but are around 15-16 ohms each. The directions I have say I can only power 2 sensors at a time with one battery/circuit and instructs me to hook them in series. But is there another way to hook them up so that I could power more sensors with one battery?

Answer (score 1):

### To set this circuit up:

- Connect the actual load to the Vo terminals (or a resistor with the same resistance value as your final load).
- Connect the (+) lead of a voltmeter to the Vo terminal near the 180 ohm resistor.  Connect the (-) voltmeter lead to Ground (the lower end of sensor3).
- Apply supply Ground to the negative side of the 200uF cap (also the lower end of sensor3).
- Apply +12V to the fuse.
- While monitoring Vo on the voltmeter, adjust the pot for proper output voltage.

Comment: And so not to have to hunt down the right resistance, he could just short `Vo` and adjust for 1.3 volts across the 12 ohm resistor. I doubt he needs regulation to three places.

Comment: Also, do you think that the line with the arrow pointing under neath the 1k trimpot from the Vadj of the voltage regulator is suppose to be another connection? I was confused what it was pointing toward or if it was suppose to be another wire connected to the #2 leg of the trimpot.  And does it matter which wires are connected to which legs of the trimpot? I apologize for my ignorance as this is a very new field for me but something I have to learn for my PhD.

Comment: Trim pots typically have 3-terminals: CW (Clockwise), CCW (Counter-Clockwise), and W (Wiper).

Comment: The W terminal can 'slide' from the CCW to the CW terminal as you adjust the trimpot.  The 'W' terminal is the line with the arrow in the schematic above. The CCW and CW terminals of the trim pot are either edge of the 1k resistor symbol.  The CW and CCW directions are not called out on the schematic.  However, by convention, one typically orients the pot so that when the pot is adjusted CW, the output of the circuit goes "up".  If your pot has only 2 terminals, then it cannot be connected as shown.

Comment: If your pot has only 2 terminals, then it's probably internally wired as a rheostat, and can't be wired as shown in your schematic.  Get a 3-terminal trim pot instead.

Comment: The pot that I have does have 3 terminals. There are two that are even with each other then another below so they are kind of in a triangle shape. I believe the one that is below is the W terminal and I currently have that facing downward on the schematic. I have the left side terminal connected to the 12 ohm resistor and the right side terminal connected to the 47 ohm resistor. The W terminal is not connected to anything currently - should it be? There are no CW or CCW labels but the bottom right corner of the pot has a 1 and the bottom left corner has a 3.    Thank you again for your help!!

Comment: I read the voltage as you described and am getting a reading of 12V (or right under that) at the V0 terminals so I know that the circuit is connected and has the correct voltage but I can't change it when I turn the trimpot, which is what makes me think I have done something incorrectly with the wiring of the pot

Comment: " The W terminal is not connected to anything currently - should it be? ": Yes!  Connect W to the right side of the 180-ohm resistor (as shown in your schematic).  "W" (wiper) is the line with the arrow.

Comment: Remember, you must have a load connected to Vo, or the circuit will not operate as intended (if it works as expected at all - I'm with @older_than_dirt_Tony on this).  Be suspicious of designs by this artist.

Comment: Okay, great. I did that, but I'm still not getting the correct voltage reading at V0. Is the wire from the Vin prong of the voltage regulator suppose to touch the wire between the two diodes?

Comment: "Is the wire from the Vin prong of the voltage regulator suppose to touch the wire between the two diodes?": yes, according to the schematic.  Maybe you should post a picture of your circuit.

Comment: A quick check shows that Iout should be adjustable from 7ma to 100mA.  Your sensors are not allowed to have an impedance of more than (12V-1.25V)/100mA ~= 10V/100mA = 100 ohms.  Unless I did the maths wrong.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen I just added a picture of a sensor in my original post. 1 sensor is composed of 2 probes (one heated, one not)